# Calling a function repeatedly using timer

Tags: c++, qt

I am calling a function foo() continuously every second that checks the serial connection ,

Now my question is that what happens if one second passes and the function foo() is not completed the previous time it was called,will the previous function get executed first or will it get suspended etc

```
checkConnection =new QTimer(this);
checkConnection->start(1000);
connect(checkConnection, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(foo()));
```

Comment: is your serial connection Class having a slot to inform you that the request timed out or succeeded?????

Comment: If your task takes a long time like 1 second then your task will block the eventloop preventing asynchronous tasks such as signal emission, call slots, etc. to work, so the answer is: Foo will not be called again. If you have a heavy task you must execute it in another thread.

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation at https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html:

> All timer types may time out later than expected if the system is busy or unable to provide the requested accuracy. In such a case of timeout overrun, Qt will emit timeout() only once, even if multiple timeouts have expired, and then will resume the original interval.

So it seems that only one timer event will exist in the queue at any one time.

That would mean your currently executing callback can take several seconds to complete and there would only be one queued in the meantime.

Comment: yes you are absolutely correct @paxdiablo i wrote a function that would definitely take more than 1 ms and called the timer every 1 ms and also printed a value each time the slot was called and the slot was indeed called after it completed and not every 1 ms.